# How to use ICU collation rules to sort the data in a JavaFX TableView?

Tags: javafx-8, icu

I wanted to use ICU collation rules to sort the (String) data in a `TableColumn` in a `TableView` using JavaFX and could not find an example online.  Here is what worked for me. (I'm assuming the reader already knows how to get data into the `TableView` since that is not what is in focus.)

Answer (score 0):

First, we import an ICU RuleBasedCollator:

```
import com.ibm.icu.text.RuleBasedCollator;
```

Second, suppose we have a Person class with first name and last name String fields.  The TableView has two TableColumns, one for the first name and one for the second name:

```
TableView<Person> personTable;
TableColumn<Person, String> firstNameColumn;
TableColumn<Person, String> lastNameColumn;
```

Third, in the view controller's initialize() method, add something like the following:

```
String newRules = "& S < C & Mu < Mue";
RuleBasedCollator collatorViaRules = new RuleBasedCollator(newRules);
Comparator<String> comparatorViaRules = Comparator.comparing(String::toString, collatorViaRules);
firstNameColumn.setComparator((String s1, String s2) -> {
            return comparatorViaRules.compare(s1, s2);
});
lastNameColumn.setComparator((String s1, String s2) -> {
            return comparatorViaRules.compare(s1, s2);
});
```

The two ICU rules in `newRules` will put any C after S and put Mu... before Mue.  (These are not intended to make great sense here; they are to see if the ICU rules are applied.  A real case could have much more complicated rules.)
We create an ICU `RuleBasedCollator` using the ICU rules and then create a `Comparator` using those rules.
Finally, we set the comparator of the column fields to use this comparator.